# Tracking pixel with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, tracking-pixel

I have a tracking pixel that I need to load in JS, at the click of a button. So the process is as follow :

1. The user clicks a link
2. I prevent the click (e.preventDefault)
3. load the tracking pixel
4. Redirect the user

Here is the code :

```
$('.btn-cta').on('click', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('body').append('<img width="1" height="1" src="http://main.exoclick.com/tag.php?goal=xyz">');
   window.location.replace($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

My problem is that not 100% of the people who click are tracked, seems like about 40/50% of them are not tracked. I don't see another method to do this, do you have a better idea to track this kind of thing in JS ?

All ideas welcome.

John

Comment: You should redirect in the `onload` event listener on the image.

Comment: @Pawei has it right: you are forwarding before the image is likely to be properly requested so the request will be cancelled when you redirect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wait for the image to load, then redirect.

```
$('.btn-cta').on('click', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var track = new Image();
    track.onload = function(){
        window.location.replace( url );
    };
    // in case the tracking server is down or misconfigured (see comments)
    // otherwise the navigation would be broken.
    track.onerror = function(){
        window.location.replace( url );
    };
    track.src = 'http://main.exoclick.com/tag.php?goal=xyz';
});
```

Comment: So the image gets loaded fine, but the onload function does NOT get executed. I don't get any error though. Maybe it's because I get this : "Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html". Any ideas ?

Comment: @JohnWolf it seems to be the case. Add an onerror event handler so you'll see it triggered when requesting this image: http://jsfiddle.net/unj4haqn/1/

Comment: yea I thought so. These guys are not good enough to give a proper MIME type. I'll look for another solution.

Comment: @JohnWolf then add the redirect to the `onerror` listener as well. While it works and records your hits it's OK, and if the third-party server is down it still won't break your website for the visitors (i.e. you should handle the onerror anyway).

Comment: Smart! I will check the data in the next 24 hours to see if it matches better. thanks a lot.

Comment: @JohnWolf glad you liked it, I've edited my answer to include onerror handling. I hope the stats will confirm it works :)

Comment: Is there anyway to trigger the pixel without using Image constructor? Just wondering why we setting the url to image src? Is there no other way?

Comment: @mannyuiux requesting an image + listening to onload / onerror have been supported for ages and are not subject to restrictive origin policies. In 2019 we could do a `fetch()` , but this would require CORS to be configured properly on the tracking server's end as well.